# JavaScript error- Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).toLocaleTimeString(...).setTimeout is not a function

Tags: javascript

Web throws error in topic to this code..

```
document.write(new Date().toLocaleTimeString().setTimeout(500));
```

What can I do with this error?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do with .setTimeout(500)? strings don't have a function named .setTimeout

Comment: I want to display time on my web app, but I want that time won't be static, will refresh every second then minute than hour... I saw on other page that for refreshing they setTimeout function and thought that maybe it will work in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A String does not have a `setTimeout` function.
If you want to display the `date` every second, you can use a `setInterval`, not a `setTimeout` which executes a function **once** after the given time in milliseconds, whereas `setInterval` executes a function continuously every few milliseconds (which is a provided argument).

```js
setInterval(function(){
   document.getElementById("time").textContent = (new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}, 1000);//displays the time every 1000 milliseconds/1 second
```

```html
<span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: @MaciejKuta No problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want to do, strings doesn't have a setTimeout function.
If you intentions are to display a date every 500ms then you can do like this.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   document.write(new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
}, 500);
```

Comment: I want to display time on my web app, but I want that time won't be static, will refresh every second then minute than hour

Comment: So do like me, but instead of document.write(that will simply add a string to the body) use document.getElementById to get an element where you want to display the time, and set innerHTML of this element to the string containing the time.